# What is KDtree alike datastructure for queries in a dynamic world?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, 3d, updates

So we have an unboundish 3d world, we need to query nearest points. Yet our points have identifiers and move all the time. What datastructure alike KDtree\Octree that would support data points . continuos movements and will not be much more bigO(N) complicated in terms of search+update than KDtree\Octree for 3d case?

Comment: It might be worth looking into [R-Trees](https://www.wikipedia.com/en/R-tree), specifically [R* Trees](https://www.wikipedia.com/en/R*_tree).

Comment: Might be worth looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamization

Comment: Maybe you could be a bit more specific about the problems you encountered, is the dataset too large? To much memory consumption? Which operation (update, kNN) poses a problem? It all depends a lot on your data...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the AABB Tree. That is a spatial datastructure used mainly for fast collision detection in games but is also the state of the art datastructure for distance computation in CGAL, libigl and similar packages. Also it is used to find the closest point on a surface as well as point containment in polyhedra and nearest neighbors.

Lastly, "Dynamic AABB Tree" is apparently used for accelerating the physics simulation of thousands of rigid bodies.

See:

http://www.randygaul.net/2013/08/06/dynamic-aabb-tree/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org) (my own). It works a little bit like a good Octree implementation with hypercube addressing (very fast updates and kNN search), but it also handles strongly clustered data very well and cannot degenerate (maximum depth is equal to the number of bits in your values, usually 32 or 64). Assuming that you want to store only points (not shapes/rectangles), you may need `PhTree` (for integer data) or `PhTreeF` (floating point data).